# Set additional info of a File in java

Tags: java, android, http

When I download a file in java I'd like to save the **getDate** value

```
URL url = new URL("http://theurl.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.getDate()
```

This way, the next time the file is needed I check the **lastModified()** VS **getDate()** and if the file changed re-download it.

My question is if is there some place or technique I can use for save the getDate() of the download moment without using a database (maybe using some special place in the file for aditional info or similar)

Note: I can't use the name of the file because it must be the original one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it really sounds like you could benefit from a meta data storage along with the file storage though...

But a hack could be to set the modified time on the file using the `java.io.File` method `setLastModified`, though that could be changed by others as well (for example by opening the file in an editor for the file) which would be bad for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It can work for my case, because the files are not saved in a public (and accessible by the user) folder. So there's no problem :D

Comment: Also, note that even if someone else changes it then it qualifies as not being the authoritative copy; in that case it's likely the app wants to download the server's version.

Answer (score 1):

The [Java API for File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) indicates there is a `setLastModified(long time)` function that you can call to set the last modified date. When you save the file locally, you can set the last modified to the getDate() call you make when you download it. Then, when you check the next time, you compare the getDate() of the download to the lastModified of the file, just like you want.